# SQL Server - Index efficiency for group by in subselects

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Attempting to make indexes that are most efficient for this setup:

View (RANKED_PHONE):

```
SELECT PHONE_ID,
       CONTACT_ID,
       TYPE_CD,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD 
                              ORDER BY UPDATE_DT DESC ) AS PHONE_RANK
FROM   (SELECT PHONE_ID,
               CONTACT_ID,
               TYPE_CD,
               UPDATE_DT
        FROM   contact_phone
        WHERE  PHONE_ID IN (SELECT MAX(PHONE_ID)
                            FROM   contact_phone WITH(NOLOCK)
                            GROUP  BY CONTACT_ID,
                                      TYPE_CD,
                                      PHONE_NUMBER)) nodupes
```

Current indices:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_contactphone_PHONEID]
  ON [contact_phone] ([PHONE_ID])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NIX_contactphone_UPDATEDT]
  ON [contact_phone] ([UPDATE_DT])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NIX_contactphone_CONTACTID_TYPECD_PHONENUMBER]
  ON [contact_phone] ([CONTACT_ID], [TYPE_CD], [PHONE_NUMBER])
GO
```

Other notes:

- There is an SSIS package that runs a lookup on PHONE_ID to check
  whether to insert or update
- This view will be further filtered in
  selects by looking for specific CONTACT_IDs filtering out PHONE_IDs
  that have been used.

EDIT:  I might as well include the rest of what I'm doing, so you can see the end picture:

```
SELECT @phone1 = COALESCE(CELL1, PERS1, BUS1, OTHER1, FAX1)
FROM(SELECT CELL1 = MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_RANK = 1 THEN CELL END)
        , PERS1 = MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_RANK = 1 THEN PERS END)
        , BUS1 = MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_RANK = 1 THEN BUS END)
        , OTHER1 = MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_RANK = 1 THEN OTHER END)
        , FAX1 = MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_RANK = 1 THEN FAX END)
    FROM(
        SELECT * FROM [RANKED_PHONE]
        WHERE CONTACT_ID = @key
    ) phone
    PIVOT(MAX(PHONE_ID) 
        FOR TYPE_CD IN ([CELL],[PERS],[BUS],[OTHER],[FAX])
    ) as pvt) phones
```

After @phone1 is selected, then "AND PHONE_ID NOT IN (@phone1)" gets added to the where clause selecting from RANKED_PHONE, and then phone2 gets added.. etc.  The point of this query is to Populate a set of phone number fields in a certain order of selection as per business rules.  I wanted to put a view in to make as much of it cached as possible.  Because of the fact that I need to filter out phone#s that have already been used, I cannot put the pivot into the view, as they need to be filtered before being pivoted.

*** MAJOR EDIT ***

A few things have changed here:

- Because I'm filtering out used phone numbers in subsequent queries, I figured I could completely strip out the de-duping section.
- I randomly found that in some instances, the UPDATE_DATE was the EXACT same, so I had to throw another field in the ORDER BY for the partition.

Also, here's some more insight on the further select statements, which may illustrate why this isn't an easy query to throw into a TVF.  The differences in the coalesce columns correspond to different output columns in the select statements (see first edit for example of the select statement):

1. ```
   SELECT @phone1 = COALESCE(CELL1, PERS1, BUS1, OTHER1, FAX1)
   ...
   WHERE CONTACT_ID = @key
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT @phone2 = COALESCE(CELL2, PERS1, PERS2, BUS1, BUS2, OTHER1, OTHER2, FAX1, FAX2)
   ... 
   WHERE CONTACT_ID = @key
       AND PHONE_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT PHONE_NUMBER FROM contact_phone WITH(NOLOCK)
           WHERE PHONE_ID IN (@phone1))
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT @phone3 = COALESCE(CELL3, PERS1, PERS2, PERS3, BUS1, BUS2, BUS3, OTHER1, OTHER2, OTHER3, FAX1, FAX2, FAX3)
   ...
   WHERE CONTACT_ID = @key
       AND PHONE_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT PHONE_NUMBER FROM contact_phone WITH(NOLOCK)
           WHERE PHONE_ID IN (@phone1,@phone2))
   ```

View [RANKED_PHONE]:

```
SELECT PHONE_ID
    , CONTACT_KEY
    , TYPE_CD
    , PHONE_NUMBER
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY CONTACT_KEY,TYPE_CD
        ORDER BY UPDATE_DATE DESC, [PRIMARY] DESC
    ) PHONE_RANK
FROM contact_phone WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Indices:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_contactphone_PHONEID] PRIMARY KEY ([PHONE_ID])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NIX_contactphone_UPDATEDATE_PRIMARY] ON [contact_phone] ([UPDATE_DATE],[PRIMARY])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NIX_contactphone_CONTACTKEY_TYPECD_PHONENUMBER] ON [contact_phone] ([CONTACT_KEY],[TYPE_CD],[PHONE_NUMBER])
GO
```

Comment: @Phrozi . . . Please tag the query with the database you are using (my guess is SQL Server based on the syntax and SSIS), especially for a performance question.

Comment: The DB type is in the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the definition of

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NIX_contactphone_CONTACTID_TYPECD_PHONENUMBER]
  ON [contact_phone] ([CONTACT_ID], [TYPE_CD], [PHONE_NUMBER])
```

To

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NIX_contactphone_CONTACTID_TYPECD_PHONENUMBER]
  ON [contact_phone] ([CONTACT_ID], [TYPE_CD], [PHONE_NUMBER], PHONE_ID DESC) 
  INCLUDE (UPDATE_DT)
```

(NB: Whilst this appears to include an extra key column this is not actually the case. The clustered index key gets added to the key of all non unique non clustered indexes anyway. However adding it explicitly allows the `ASC`/`DESC` to be defined.)

The index does have an extra `INCLUDE`-d column to cover the query though.

And change the query to

```
SELECT PHONE_ID,
       CONTACT_ID,
       TYPE_CD,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD 
                              ORDER BY UPDATE_DT DESC ) AS PHONE_RANK
FROM   (SELECT PHONE_ID,
               CONTACT_ID,
               TYPE_CD,
               UPDATE_DT,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD, PHONE_NUMBER 
                                        ORDER BY PHONE_ID DESC) AS PHONE_ID_RANK
        FROM   contact_phone
        ) nodupes 
        WHERE PHONE_ID_RANK = 1
```

That slightly improves the plan.

[image: Plan]

The ordering used by the first partition of `CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD, PHONE_NUMBER, PHONE_ID DESC` does not match that desired by the second part of the query `CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD,UPDATE_DT` though so you will always get a sort.

Comment: Martin, two things - I was wondering about either including the UPDATE_DT all in one index, or including it as an include, because the execution path does show all 4 columns in the hash match, but I was wondering how effective that would be because it is the order by in the select.  The other is that yes, I am trying to get rid of the monstrous sort.  Currently it's at 69%.. I'd like to move most of the workload to the indexes.

Comment: @Phrozt -  Grouping by `CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD, PHONE_NUMBER` doesn't provide any order that can be used by the `ROW_NUMBER` as the third required sort column is `UPDATE_DT`. Do your queries against the view actually need the entire `ROW_NUMBER`? If you are only interested in `PHONE_RANK = 1` for example there might be a way to avoid it.

Comment: Martin - actually PHONE_ID is the clustered index, because it will be used to filter the view and it is used in the SSIS loading lookup. I'm a bit confused as to why the sub select was changed?

Comment: @Phrozt - Yes I realised that afterwards. The sub select was changed to give a more efficient plan with the suggested index change. It replaces a scan + correlated index seek that I see in the original query with just a scan. Of course with your data you may get an entirely different plan anyway so you need to evaluate it yourself.

Comment: @Phrozt - Well there's probably a much simpler way of doing whatever it is that you are trying to do but a really simple quick improvement will be to use an inline parameterised TVF instead of a view and put the `WHERE CONTACT_ID = @key` right inside the initial query. At the moment it will be bringing back and sorting rows for all `CONTACT_ID` and applying the filter at the end.

Comment: @Phrozt - See [The Problem with Window Functions and Views](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views) for more info about the issue I mention above.

Comment: Martin - I learned a LOOOT from that article!  Thanks for posting it.  I really wish I could use the WITH TIES function more, because the code I'm trying to optimize uses ROW_NUMER/PARTITION BY (some date) all over the place.  Unfortunately, the dates needed vary quite a bit, so that's not an option :/.  Thanks again for the education.

Answer (score 0):

@Phrozt - your original indexes look fine as is except I would go ahead and make your clustered index unique.

There's a problem with your view definition though that leads to poor performance. The innermost subquery is only connected to the outer query by PHONE_ID ("WHERE  PHONE_ID IN..."). Because of that the query optimizer does not know that you are actually deduping the numbers for that one CONTACT_ID, and ends up deduping the entire table.

I suggest changing the view to something like this:

```
SELECT PHONE_ID,
       CONTACT_ID,
       TYPE_CD,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD 
                              ORDER BY UPDATE_DT DESC ) AS PHONE_RANK
FROM   (SELECT p.PHONE_ID,
               p.CONTACT_ID,
               p.TYPE_CD,
               p.UPDATE_DT
        FROM   contact_phone p
        INNER JOIN (SELECT CONTACT_ID, TYPE_CD, MAX(PHONE_ID) AS PHONE_ID
                    FROM   contact_phone WITH(NOLOCK)
                    GROUP  BY CONTACT_ID,
                              TYPE_CD,
                              PHONE_NUMBER) t
            ON p.CONTACT_ID = t.CONTACT_ID AND p.TYPE_CD = t.TYPE_CD AND p.PHONE_ID = t.PHONE_ID
) nodupes
```

Also, as a side note, I doubt that using the view vs. just including the entire thing in the final query will make any noticeable difference performance-wise.

Comment: @Phrozt - Reading your comments, "...I am trying to get rid of the monstrous sort. Currently it's at 69%..." it sounds to me like you are trying to tune  the statement SELECT * FROM RANKED_PHONE. You should not be doing that unless that is what the application will be doing. Sounds like that's not the case. I also agree with Martin about inline TVF. Or just get rid of the view and make one big select.

Comment: Vlad - RANKED_PHONE contains every column I need to continue, so that's why I'm selecting *.  I implemented the inner join as you suggested, but it seems to take a bit longer. Perhaps because of the group by?

Comment: My suggestion should help your "SELECT @phone1 = COALESCE(PERS1, BUS1, OTHER1, PERS2, BUS2, OTHER2) .... WHERE CONTACT_ID = @key" query in your original post. Is this what you're trying to tune? I also assumed that you have not changed your indexes except for making the CLUSTERED index unique. Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2008r2.  Yes you are correct that I haven't changed anything except to make PHONE_ID a primary key

Comment: It worked fine on my box :). No expensive sorts. Maybe if you post the XML query plan I could pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Vlad - I actually stripped out the de-duping part.  I added the check in the subsequent selects.  I'll update my original post.